# Fetch requests inside onClick abort when downloading a file in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, firefox, download

I'm trying to create a link which downloads a file and at the same time send a fetch request via `onClick` to notify a server that the file has been downloaded.

The issue is that in Firefox, the fetch request is not sent and the error `TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.` appears in the console. It seems that downloading a file interrupts the fetch request in firefox for some reason. But it seems to work fine in chrome.

Sample code here, try it in Firefox to see the error: https://codesandbox.io/s/anchor-onclick-download-fevtm?fontsize=14

I would like to ask why is this happening in Firefox and what could be an alternative solution to achieve the desired behavior.

Adding `target="_blank"` will make this work, but I would like to do this behavior without opening a tab for UX reasons.

Comment: its working well in chrome, maybe try firefox in incognito mode, maybe some plugin preventing this action

Comment: I'm using a fresh install of firefox so I doubt that its plugin related. Also I noticed the same issue happens in safari with the error message:  `Failed to load resource: Frame load interrupted`

Comment: chech this buddy: https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/5yhwob/fetch_api_not_working_in_firefox_addon/ 
it says he created manifest.json permissions and its solved the problem

Comment: I don't think it's exactly the same problem though, since other `fetch()` requests in Firefox works. It is only in this scenario where you send a fetch request via onClick and download a file at the same time where the error occurs. It seems that downloading a file interrupts the fetch request in firefox for some reason.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286442/not-working-onclick-on-firefox-chrome-and-safari

Answer (score 0):

Firefox [claims to follow the spec](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1084399), and there's a [spec](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=27347) [issue](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/4489) about this.

Perhaps [`<a download>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes) will help?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the spec issues!

`<a download>` didn't work, what I did is to just programmatically mount and click the <a> tag (used [file-saver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/)) after waiting for the fetch request to be finished